# display items from another site in my web site using Magento

Tags: magento

Hai

I want to do an e-commerce site in magento. Here I want to display items from petco.com to my site, like done in http://www.terrificpets.com. But I don't know any idea about this. Does any one know? Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento will only display items from its own internal catalog, and changing it to display things not in the catalog would be a difficult process. That means that you need to get the PETCO supplies into your product catalog so that you can sell them in your store.

The fastest way to do this would be to find a CSV output of the catalog items and use the Import/Export facilities of magento. If that isn't available, an RSS feed or XML output of the items in their catalog would be helpful, but you would need to write a little code to take those XML items and save them into the Magento database. Use the Magento webservice classes for this.

Finally, if none of that is available, you'll most likely have to put the items in by hand. Only use this as a last resort, as updating the in-stock availability and prices for these items will be a real pain.

Hope that helps. Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. But still I have doubt. I heard about the Affiliate Program in petco and I have the Cj account. I got the showcase code from Affiliate Program link. I know, by putting the code in an html page I got the product list. My doubt is how or where I put that code in magento. Please replay.

Comment: If you just want to echo someone else's HTML, try creating a CMS page for the content. This would not integrate w/ your Magento site in any way, though. You'd have to use their checkout & accounting and such. If I'm misunderstanding, please edit your post w/ some of the code.